# How to change date timestamp from unix to localDateString in event listener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a homework of Javascript exercise that goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Producst</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body dir="rtl">
    <main id="root"></main>
    <button class="btn" id="changeProducts">Make Changes</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here we have 5 products that are getting written at `<main id="root"></main>` like this:

[image]

And this content comes from the `script.js` which holds:

```
const main = document.getElementById('root');

function renderProducts(products) {
  main.innerHTML = products
    .map(
      product => `<div class="product" data-product-id="${product.id}">
                    <h1>${product.title}</h1>
                    <p class="price">${product.price} Toman</p>
                    <p class="date">${product.date}</p>
                  </div>`
    )
    .join('');
}

const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Product 1',
    price: '32000',
    date: '1596902113'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Product 2',
    price: '46000',
    date: '1555891200'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Product 3',
    price: '20000',
    date: '1515369600'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Product 4',
    price: '88000',
    date: '1509580800'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Product 5',
    price: '11000',
    date: '1477267200'
  }
];

renderProducts(products);

document
  .getElementById('changeProducts')
  .addEventListener('click', changeProducts);

function changeProducts() {
    main.innerHTML = products
    .map(
      product => `<div class="product" data-product-id="${product.id}">
                    <h1>${product.title}</h1>
                    <p class="price">${product.price / 2} تومان</p>
                    <p class="date">${product.date}</p>
                  </div>`
    )
    .join('');
}
```

So after user clicks on **Make Changes** button, the function `changeProducts()` will run and it will basically subtract the number by half and also **should convert the `product.date` to localDateString**.

So I know for converting, the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript) is useful, but I don't know how to call the code inside `changeProducts` function!!

So if you know, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `${new Date(product.date * 1000).toLocaleDateString()}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `product.date` to `new Date(product.date * 1000).toLocaleDateString()`

```
function changeProducts() {
    main.innerHTML = products
    .map(
      product => `<div class="product" data-product-id="${product.id}">
                    <h1>${product.title}</h1>
                    <p class="price">${product.price / 2} تومان</p>
                    <p class="date">${new Date(product.date * 1000).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
                  </div>`
    )
    .join('');
}
```